# set fixed width and height of webpart using css

Tags: web-part

While changing the text within a list based webpart, the size of the WebPart changes, resulting in alignment of the webpart getting distorted.

Any suggestions on how to take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using any of following technique which suits better for your requirement.

1. While developing WebPart keep all UI block in a parent element, and set a fixed width to it.
2. If using OOTB WebPart use content editor WebPart, add css and mark !important, so it will override the default Css properties.
3. After adding WebPart to WebPart zone, go to WebPart properties, specify  width and height
4. Create own custom WebPart page with fixed width WebPart zones to it, and then add your WebPart.

Comment: Gaurravs,

I`ve 3 webparts already created and are part of same webpartzone.
One of the webpart is fetching data from a list.
Whenever the content in the list is changed, it disturbs the alignment.

I tried using CSS with !important;, not getting the exact result and was wondering if a easier path.

As you may agree, in case of CSS. YOu need to add CSS code and see effect, again start the process to add additional CSS code or modify.

Comment: Cann't you add new webpart to another zone?

Comment: Add your new webpart, keep page in edit mode, select your webpart which needs fixed width, go to webpart properties, In Appearance section, provide fixed height and width, This will impact only to that specific webpart and not others even if all resides in same zone